# Fetching the column values inside the grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my table, having 5 row 4 columns, I want to fetch only 3 rd column data values present in all the rows.

Can anyone give me a code template to achieve this task?

Comment: Please provide the html if possible

Comment: Likely you will need to use XPath for this. Having the table ID will absolutely help, and here are some examples of accessing tr and td. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f284f973-95e9-4f29-98cf-5ccc234adc9b/xpath-query-help?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: Yes its worked for me , i fetched using xpath....Thanks Adam

Answer (score -1):

your code will be something like:

```
    List<String> values = new List<String>();

    int row =5;

    for (int i=1; i<=row; i++)
    {
         values.add(driver.Find(By.XPath(".//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]").Text) ;
    }
```